# Flexslider, Disable mousewheel after/on the last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am currently using mouse-wheel to go from slide to slide.  The slider I have is full screen so you cannot scroll passed it.  This works out great, but I want to disable the mousewheel function of the flexslider so that on the last slide they can scroll freely either passed it, or back above it.  I currently have the follow:

```
 $('#main_slider .flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "fade",
      animationSpeed: 650,
      move: 1,
      controlNav: false,
      directionNav: false,
      mousewheel: false,  
      animationLoop: false,
      start: function(slider){
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
      },
      before: function(slider){

        //console.log(slider)

        //  Determine which slide we're moving to
          // slidingTo = slider.animatingTo;
          //console.log('sliding to: '+slidingTo);

          $('.flexslider .slides > li').removeClass('hovered');
      },
      after: function(slider){

        $('.flex-active-slide').addClass('hovered');
        //console.log('triggered mouse');
        if (slider.currentSlide == 1) { // TO SEE IF THE CURRENT SLIDE IS 2 TEST...
          $('.flex-active-slide.hovered').css('background','blue')
        }
        if (slider.currentSlide == 2) { // TO SEE IF THE CURRENT SLIDE IS 3 TEST...
          $('.flex-active-slide.hovered').css('background','red')
        }

      },
      end: function(){

        slider.pause();

        WHAT GOES HERE TO DISABLE THE FLEX SLIDER MOUSE-WHEEL FUNCTION??

      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this ended up doing the trick (went in the end function)

```
$('#main_slider .flexslider').unmousewheel();
```

Comment: Hey, where is the unmousewheel() function?

Comment: It worked great and stopped mousewheel at last slide. But we have another problem here. When we scroll back to top of screen, flexslider should start again using mousewheel but its not working anymore. Do you have any solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I was able to turn off mouse wheel scrolling in my horizontal slider !!

```
   }
    // MOUSEWHEEL:
    if (vars.mousewheel) {
      slider.bind('**unmousewheel**', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = (delta < 0) ? slider.getTarget('next') : slider.getTarget('prev');
        slider.flexAnimate(target, vars.pauseOnAction);
      });
    }

    // PAUSEPLAY
    if (vars.pausePlay) methods.pausePlay.setup();
```